# Is there better way to rig this mechanical object?

Tags: rigging, constraints, parent

I have an object consisting of 4 tubes and 4 pivot points.

[image: Start]

I'd like to be able to "skew" the object like this (it can only skew left/right, not in the third dimension):

[image]

I managed to get it working, but it seems hacky:

- Parented top_pivot.L and bot_pivot.L to tube.L
- Parented top_pivot.R and bot_pivot.R to tube.R
- Added copy rotation to tube.R (copy from tube.L)
- Added copy location to tube.bot (copy from bot_pivot.L)
- Added copy location to tube.top (copy from top_pivot.L)
- Finally offset tube.top and tube.bot middle points (over the pivots.L)
- optionally limit the rotation of tube.L to prevent the top and bot tubes from intersecting

So when tube.L rotates, the whole thing skews because of the constraints.

The problems start when I try and parent tube.L and tube.R to other objects, or when I try and move/rotate pieces.

Can this whole thing be done with armature/bones?

**Update** an example of a problem when using the object as part of a bigger one:

Attaching the base and linking to tube.L:

[image]

rotating the base causes the child objects to rotate in an unwanted way:

[image]

Comment: Can you describe a little bit more about the parenting arrangements with other objects that are giving you problems?